# How to create a stacked cards with rotate slider in flutter with animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I want to create a container that holds 5 cards
In the image below the design is showing how it should looks like
I need only to know how to create this Stack containers with Slider
When I Slide from one to another it should Animate from one to another but it should stay in the main container range width.
Anyone can help with this functionality?

here is the design:

[image: image design]

Comment: Will all 5 card be visible at the same time? And can you include what you've tried so far

Comment: Yes all cards will be visible at the same time the only change that they scroll and the index changing i'll add the code too.

Comment: You can check `carousel_slider` and pageView widget